# Finding the force ground applied to the object.

Tags: physics

[image]

An object whose mass is $m$ is crashing into the ground and leaping with the same velocity. If the duration of the interaction between the object and the ground is $0.1$ seconds, determine the force ground applied to the object.

I know that

$$\Delta P_y = F_y \times \Delta t$$

$$\Delta P_y = (N-mg) \times \Delta t$$

$$2mv_0 \sin \theta  = (N-mg) \times \Delta t$$

Hence we get

$$N = 220N$$

According to answer key, it seems incorrect.

Comment: Is there anyone who can take a look at it?

Comment: I'm still having trouble...

Comment: `mg` plays no role here.

Comment: @user58697 I realized that.

Comment: Really, Isn't there anyone?

Comment: So, drop $mg$ and you are done: $200 N$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually this is an impulse force which is triangular in shape. However, assuming its a constant force (rectangular), then it should be:

The normal velocity is $5m/s$ to the ground. It reduces to $0 m/s$ in $.05$ seconds. So $F = ma$ therefore:
$$ F = 2\cdot \frac{5}{.05} = 200 N$$